# Create tablespace in PostgreSQL RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am new to Amazon RDS.
I'm trying to create a tablespaces for my application, but I can't find where I should store it.

Is it possible to create tablespaces in PostgreSQL RDS?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html

Answer (score 9):

I didn't find RDS documentation about this, but apparently Postgres tablespaces work fine on RDS. You don't have direct access to the underlying EBS volume that RDS is using, but if you try a CREATE TABLESPACE command with some arbitrary directory:

`CREATE TABLESPACE testspace LOCATION '/foo/bar/baz';`

You can see that the tablespace gets created like so:

`mydb=> \db
                         List of tablespaces
    Name    |   Owner    |                 Location

------------+------------+-------------------------------------------
 pg_default | rdsadmin   | 
 pg_global  | rdsadmin   | 
 testspace  | db_user    | /rdsdbdata/db/base/tablespace/foo/bar/baz
(3 rows)`

And you should be able to create tables in that tablespace just fine:

`mydb=> CREATE TABLE test (a int) TABLESPACE testspace ;
CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 4):

At the time of writing in 2019 RDS does support PostgreSQL tablespaces, although not for IO splitting or isolation (as all tablespaces will be created on the same volume). AWS documentation for this feature can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Tablespaces).

Answer (score 3):

Things like log-shipping/standby servers heavily depend on tablespace location. I wouldn't risk it and blindly use a location I don't have access to and not fully aware of(as Josh suggested)

I guess we just all have to admit it that much as we like AWS services, there are things where they lag behind, especially with regards to SaaS solutions to external\independent products(RDS, Docker orchestration on ECS, etc.)

**UPDATE:**
If this [post](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2015/07/15/scaling-postgres-rds-with-pg-shard/) is correct, RDS replication for Postgres does depend on streaming replication, which makes any manipulations with tablespace paths very dangerous unless you can find it in their official docs or via enterprise support that such strategy will always work as you expect.