# AWS RDS PostgreSQL Tablespace

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created an AWS RDS postgres instance. When creating i was prompted to create user. There is no reason for creating tablespaces with location in AWS RDS? The reason is when creating a database i want the database to goto the tablespace i created. When i run the below command

```
CREATE USER test;

CREATE TABLESPACE test OWNER test LOCATION '/test_data';

CREATE DATABASE test WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'C' LC_CTYPE = 'C' TABLESPACE = test;

ERROR:  permission denied for tablespace test
```

I logged into postgres using test_admin user to run the above commands. The test_admin is the account i created during the RDS instance provisioning. Is that the only account that i should be using above to create all of the DB objects from that point?

Comment: Do you really expect to be able to write to the root directory of the RDS machine?

Comment: AWS RDS append the default path even though you specify the path /test_data/. This is what i see in the tablespace. /rdsdbdata/db/base/tablespace/test_data

Answer (score 1):

Tablespaces in postgres RDS are located in `/rdsdbdata/db/base/tablespace/`

and I think this question has been answered here
[Create tablespace on PostgreSQL RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616672/create-tablespace-on-postgresql-rds#41599188)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the owner of the database to be `test` as well? If so, add that into your `CREATE DATABASE...`. Otherwise, you'll probably need to give the `test_admin` user permission on the `test` tablespace before trying to create it.